# Analyze the intersection of two numeric vectors and create pie chart

Tags: r, vector, pie-chart, intersection

I'm having two vectors with numeric values:

```
v.typA <- c(1,2,110,111,20,22,46,80,89,100,210,320,999,1000)            # length = 14
v.typB <- c(1,2,10,11,20,22,40,44,60,66,80,88,100,210,320,430,540,666)  # length = 18
```

Now I want to create a pie chart, which visualizes the unique values and duplicates of these two vectors in percentage. I'm thinking of something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is the difference between "non-unique" and "duplicates"?

Comment: Sorry, I was just a bit confused of this pic. Of course I want to visualise the percentage of duplicates and unique values.

Comment: Is NULL also included in the unique count, or separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something like this in mind?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

v.typA <- c(1,2,110,111,20,22,46,80,89,100,210,320,999,1000)      
v.typB <- c(1,2,10,11,20,22,40,44,60,66,80,88,100,210,320,430,540,666)
vec <- c(v.typA,v.typB)

df <- tibble(var = c("Unique", "Duplicated"),
             val = c(length(unique(vec)), length(vec) - length(unique(vec)))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(var)) %>%
  mutate(prop = val / sum(val) *100) %>%
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(prop)- 0.5*prop )

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=prop, fill=var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = paste0(var,", ", prop,"%")), color = "white", size=6) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

Comment: Here ```df <- tibble()``` I get the following Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `prop`.
i `prop = val/sum(df$val) * 100`.
x object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: replace with `val/sum(.$val) * 100`

Comment: sorry, I updated the answer.  I also added percentages to the plot.